# Tomcat 6 doesn't decode + to space in parameter values

Tags: tomcat, parameters, url-encoding

I have to OpenSUSE 10.4 machines running my webapp in Tomcat 6.0.32 (as provided by zypper), but in one of the instances '+' in parameter values is not decoded to ' ', and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Both tomcats have been configured manually, and so they might not be running with the same settings, but I can't think of a setting that would cause this behavior.

EDIT: Both instances use URIEncoding="UTF-8". I've also tried without setting the URIEncoding attribute, but it makes no difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an issue with the specific Tomcat build on OpenSuSE.  I am running OpenSuSE 11.4 and had this exact same issue.  A simple YaST update corrected it.

Tomcat version that errored: tomcat6-6.0.32-7.12.1.noarch
    (really tomcat6-*-6.0.32-7.12.1.noarch)

Version that worked: tomcat6-6.0.32-7.14.1.noarch

Comment: Thank you! I had only looked at the tomcat version (6.0.32) and assumed it was the same build. I wonder why 7.14.1 wasn't picked from the start? The failing server was configured more recently than   the working server - one would think that zypper, by default, would have picked a more recent version of tomcat? Anyways, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an encoding issue.

Try adding the UTF-8 encoding to the Connector of [TOMCAT_HOME]/home/server.xml:

e.g:

`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" />`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I should have mentioned this - both instances use URIEncoding="UTF-8". I've also tested without it - no difference. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 1):

On OpenSuSE 11.3 this is related specifically to the tomcat6-6.0.24-5.16.1 package and you can work around it by downgrading to the previous tomcat package. I ran into this with Confluence, https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-24659, and it took awhile to debug.

1. downgrade tomcat:

   ```
   zypper install --force tomcat6-6.0.24-5.14.1.noarch
   ```
2. Add a package lock to online_updates don't apply the busted package

   zypper addlock tomcat6

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same problem on some OpenSuSE 11.3 servers running tomcat6-6.0.24-5.16.1.
My pages are encoded in ISO-8859-1 though.

Anyway, I've done some testing and noticed that if the parameters I submit in my test form contains non-ascii characters, such as Swedish ÅÄÖ or dollar or percent, the parameter is encoded/decoded correctly. But if the parameter value only contains regular ASCII chars, such as "This sucks", the encoding/decoding doesn't seem to be triggered, leaving spaces as +.

The problem does not exist if the form has enctype multipart/form-data.

Edit:

I can verify that updating Tomcat work.
I updated to tomcat6-6.0.35-42.2.noarch.